# Actual argument String cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion - how to fix it

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fragment, converters

Hello i have this error:

```
Error:(36, 19) error: constructor DrawerItem in class DrawerItem cannot be applied to given types;
required: int,int,Class<? extends Fragment>
found: String,int,Class<TODOFragment_>
reason: actual argument String cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion
Note: C:\Users\Kisiel\AndroidStudioProjects\Studentizer\app\src\main\java\pl\edu\ug\aib\studentizerApp\fragment\TimetableFragment.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

This is my code TODOFragment:

```
package pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Fragment;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.EFragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.R;
import pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.todoList.DatabaseHandler;
import pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.todoList.Task;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_todo)
public class TODOFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText zadanieTxt, opisTxt, dataTxt, adresTxt;
    List<Task> Tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    ListView TaskListView;
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todo, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        zadanieTxt = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtZadanie);
        opisTxt = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtOpis);
        dataTxt = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtData);
        adresTxt = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtAdres);
        TaskListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) getView().findViewById(R.id.baner);

        tabHost.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Dodaj zadanie");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabZadanie);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Dodaj Zadanie");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("lista");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabListaZadan);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Lista");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        final Button addBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Task task = new Task(dbHandler.getTaskCount(), String.valueOf(zadanieTxt.getText()), String.valueOf(opisTxt.getText()), String.valueOf(dataTxt.getText()), String.valueOf(adresTxt.getText()));
                if (!taskExists(task)) {
                    dbHandler.createZadanie(task);
                    Tasks.add(task);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(zadanieTxt.getText()) + " zostało dodane do listy zadań!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(zadanieTxt.getText()) + " Zadanie już istnieje", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        zadanieTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                addBtn.setEnabled(String.valueOf(zadanieTxt.getText()).trim().length() > 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });



        if (dbHandler.getTaskCount() != 0)
            Tasks.addAll(dbHandler.getAllTasks());

        populateList();
    }

    private boolean taskExists(Task task) {
        String zadanie = task.getZadanie();
        int taskCount = Tasks.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++) {
            if (zadanie.compareToIgnoreCase(Tasks.get(i).getZadanie()) == 0)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    private void populateList() {
        ArrayAdapter<Task> adapter = new TaskListAdapter();
        TaskListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class TaskListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {
        public TaskListAdapter()
        {

            super (TODOFragment.this.getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item, Tasks);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (view == null)
                view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

            Task currentTask = Tasks.get(position);

            TextView zadanie = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.zadanie);
            zadanie.setText(currentTask.getZadanie());
            TextView opis = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.opis);
            opis.setText(currentTask.getOpis());
            TextView data = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data);
            data.setText(currentTask.getData());
            TextView adres = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adres);
            adres.setText(currentTask.getAdres());

            return view;
        }
    }



}
```

And DrawerListAdapter

```
package pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.navigationDrawer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.AfterInject;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.RootContext;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.R;
import pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment.TODOFragment_;
import pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment.TimetableFragment_;
import pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment.DashboardFragment_;
import pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment.WalletFragment_;

@EBean
public class DrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @RootContext
    Context context;

    List<DrawerItem> items = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();

    @AfterInject
    void init() {
        items.clear();

        //Dodawanie do Drawera listy fragmentów
        items.add(new DrawerItem(R.string.title_dashboard, R.drawable.icon_home, DashboardFragment_.class));
        items.add(new DrawerItem(R.string.title_timetable, R.drawable.ic_directions_transit_white_24dp, TimetableFragment_.class));
        items.add(new DrawerItem("Lista zadań", R.drawable.icon_about, TODOFragment_.class));
        items.add(new DrawerItem(R.string.title_wallet, R.drawable.wallet_grey, WalletFragment_.class));
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        DrawerItemView drawerItemView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            drawerItemView = DrawerItemView_.build(context);
        } else {
            drawerItemView = (DrawerItemView) convertView;
        }

        drawerItemView.bind(getItem(position));

        return drawerItemView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public DrawerItem getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


}
```

I Already I searched many topics on the forum but did not find answers how I can fix it. I hope that some of you help me. If I have put some pieces of code, write it in the comments.

```
package pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.navigationDrawer;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class DrawerItem {

    private int titleResId;
    private int iconResId;
    private Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass;

    public DrawerItem(int titleResId, int iconResId, Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass) {
        this.titleResId = titleResId;
        this.iconResId = iconResId;
        this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
    }

    public int getTitleResId() {
        return titleResId;
    }

    public int getIconResId() {
        return iconResId;
    }

    public Class<? extends Fragment> getFragmentClass() {
        return fragmentClass;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `DrawerItem` constructor that takes a `String` argument? Is `DrawerItem` your own class?

Comment: After the new changes check if error if different and post it

Comment: You're right, it is a little bit different error. Now is
Error:(36, 19) error: constructor DrawerItem in class DrawerItem cannot be applied to given types;
required: int,int,Class<? extends Fragment>
found: int,int,Class<TODOFragment_>
reason: actual argument Class<TODOFragment_> cannot be converted to Class<? extends Fragment> by method invocation conversion

Comment: There you're, your class is 'TODOFragment', not `TODOFragment_`. Check that `TODOFragment_` is actually a fragment

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question, but how can i check this ?

Comment: Check that extends Fragment

Comment: I rebuild project but it doesnt help :/

Answer (score 2):

The error is in here

```
items.add(new DrawerItem("Lista zadań", R.drawable.icon_about, TODOFragment_.class));
```

You are passing an `String` as parameters and it should be and `int`. Put `"Lista zadań"` in the resources and pass it as the other strings

Comment: @Elenasys Not it is not, it is and integer. `getResources().getString(R.string.title_dashboard )` is the string

Comment: Yes i Know is an integer check my answer and my first post. :)

Comment: I have posted first that an integer is needed, please don´t copy my answer. =)

Comment: @Elenasys Shame on you

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect, the method `DrawerItem()` must receive an int value.

```
items.add(new DrawerItem("Lista zadań", R.drawable.icon_about, TODOFragment_.class));  //ERROR! :P
```

so add into your Strings.xml file:

```
<string name="title_lista">Lista zadań</string>
```

then change the third line to:

```
items.add(new DrawerItem(R.string.title_lista, R.drawable.icon_about, TODOFragment_.class));  //ERROR! :P
```